# Wordpress & jQuery Cycle Plugin - How to get caption from div that contins the_title() and the_excerpt()

Tags: wordpress, jquery-cycle, caption

I'm trying to use jQuery Cycle Plugin within a theme that I'm currently developing. I've got the jQuery Cycle to display slideshow of post images on the home page. However, my problem is that I can't get it to display the content of a div that contains the_title() and the_excerpt() as a caption correctly.
I'm using the following code:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $('#slideshow').cycle({
            fx:       'fadeZoom',
            timeout:   2000,
            after: onAfter
        });
    });
    function onAfter(curr,next,opts) {
        var caption = $('.featured-entry').text();
        $('#caption').html(caption);
    }
</script>

<div id="container">
    <div class="pics" id="slideshow">
        <?php
            $slideshow_posts = new WP_Query('cat=3&posts_per_page=5');
            while($slideshow_posts->have_posts())
                $slideshow_posts->the_post();
                $picture = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'picture', true);
                if(!empty($picture))
                {
                ?>
                    <div class="slideshow-inner">
                        <a class="featured-article" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><img src="<?php echo $picture; ?>" /></a>
                        <div class="featured-entry">
                            <a class="entry-title" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                            <div class="entry-summary"><?php the_excerpt() ?></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                <?php
                }
            }
        ?>
    </div>
    <div id="caption"></div>
</div>
```

The problem with this code is that it only displays the_excerpt of one post for all slides. Meaning that the_excerpt does not change when the image changes.

So what's I'm missing? This is my first work with jQuery, and I hope someone could help me with this.

**P.S. I know how to get caption from img's attributes such as 'alt', but I don't want to do it that way and I want to get the caption from the content of a div.**

Regards

-XO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/KCkUa/):

```
function onAfter(curr, next, opts) {
    var caption = $(next).find('.featured-entry').text();
    $('#caption').html(caption);
}
```

`$('featured-entry')` should btw. never work — it's not a valid selector.

Comment: I must have -unintentionally- removed the dot(.) which was before the class name when I was reformatting the code; I've edited my post. Anyway, Your code seems to work as desired. Thanks.

Comment: Hi again polarblau, is there anyway to do some transition effects to the caption div such as scrollUp? also let it disappear when the slid change? Thanks.

Comment: You should be able to use the `onAfter` and `onBefore` callbacks to do pretty much what you want with the `#caption` div. Try e.g. `$('#caption').fadeOut()` in `onBefore` and then`$('#caption').html(caption).fadeIn()` in `onAfter`. That should give you an idea if I'm not wrong.

Comment: Yes, that works like a charm, thanks. I wanted to vote for your answer but I still don't have enough reputation to do so, all I can do is thanking you. Thanks again.